# SAMSUNG GALAXY S DUOS 2 (GT-S7582) turning on for 2 second only

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-duos-2

my SAMSUNG GALAXY S DUOS 2 (GT-S7582) turning on for 2 second only and then switch off again.
I already check with other charge battery but same problem occur.

I also try to root phone by holding VOLUME DOWN+HOME KEY+POWER KEY TOGETHER but same issue.

I'm not identify that is hardware issue or software issue.

Please advise me and give solution.

Thanks!

Comment: So the phone is unrooted? Holding volume down and power and home just opens Download mode, volume up is recovery IIRC. Can you try recovery mode? Is it shutting down the same? It sounds like a hardware issue to be honest, but do the recovery first. Does it shut down even when plugged in?

Comment: @RossC: i tried but still same maybe it's hardware issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution - I just cleaned the battery node and it's working 100%

After removing the battery, on top you will find three battery charging points (nodes), take a pin or any screw driver (or similar) and scrape on the three points and then clean the surface.

Now insert the battery on mobile then switch ON.